# Jackson deserialize JsonIdentityReference (alwaysAsId = true)

Tags: java, json, jackson

Following up on this question: [Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096216/jackson-serialize-deserialize-property-as-json-value)

`@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)` and 
`@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class)` works great from the Serialization end, but not so well when it comes time to deserialize since it can't resolve the Object ID reference.

Is there a way to get this to deserialize?  Writing a custom deserializer seems like overkill.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of a custom deserializer, you can use a simple setter deserializer:

```
public class Container {
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    private Foo foo;

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
    public Container setFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
        return this;
    }
    @JsonProperty("foo")
    public void setFoo(String id) {
        foo = new Foo().setId(id);
    }
}
```

Example string of `{"foo":"id1"}` is serialized properly with this method in `Jackson 2.5.2`

Comment: This does not work if Foo has more properties than just the id and, thus, existing instances have to be linked.

Comment: setId shoudln't return instance of Foo, you should make it a builder insted