# single custom serializer for all embedded annotated objects that replaces them with their ids

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, spring-data

I have entities like those:

```
@Entity
public Product {
   @Id
   public int id;

   public String name;

   @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH} )
   Category category

   @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH} )
   Set<Category> secondaryCategories;


}
```

and

```
@Entity
public Category {
   @Id
   public int id;

   public String name;

    @JsonCreator
    public Category(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Category() {}
}
```

is it possible to annotate either just `Category` class or `category` and `secondaryCategories` properties with an annotation that will serialize them to be just their ids when they are embedded.

right now I am getting from the server when I make a GET for product with id=1:

```
{ 
  id: 1,
  name: "product 1", 
  category: {id: 2, name: "category 2" }, 
  secondaryCategories: [{id: 3, name: "category 3" }, 
                        {id: 4, name: "category 4" }, 
                        {id: 5, name: "category 5" }] 
}
```

is it possible to get back:

```
{ 
  id: 1,
  name: "product 1", 
  category: 2, 
  secondaryCategories: [3, 4, 5]
}
```

Annotating `Category` class with `@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)`
works generally but also returns just ids when I am fetching one or a list of Categories. I need id conversion only when Category is embedded.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)` on the category variable only.

E.g.:

```
@Entity
public Product {
   @Id
   public int id;

   public String name;

   @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH} )
   @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope=Category.class)
   @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
   Category category;

   @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH} )
   Set<Category> secondaryCategories;


}
```

Comment: oh I didnt try that annotation on the property! I will give it a try and tell you! One more question since the FetchType is LAZY will this cut the join with the category table?

Comment: I tried it and I still get embedded objects - anything that I am missing?

Comment: I have updated code to specify property name using `@JsonIdentityInfo`. I think this would work.

Comment: while it worked for Serialization (GET) it probably clashed with @JsonCreator constructor  of Category during deserialization (PUT/POST) - I am getting: 
`org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"JSON parse error: Unresolved forward references for: ; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.UnresolvedForwardReference`

Comment: I removed @JsonCreator and still my PUT/POST fails (I am sending just ids for category and secondaryCategories)

Comment: Have you added default constructor in `Category` class

Comment: when I removed @JsonCreator constructor I removed the default one too

Comment: try to add default one too

Comment: and add scope param in  `@JsonIdentityInfo`, as described in updtaed answer

Comment: you know that in a Java class a default constructor is always implied if you don't define your own right? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4488766/986160 - so I don't need to try that

Comment: scope param? I don't see it

Comment: same issue: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.UnresolvedForwardReference: Unresolved forward references for: \n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@692bc560; line: 1, column: 371]Object id [1]

Comment: Chk this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007188/deserialize-json-with-spring-unresolved-forward-references-jackson-exception

Comment: Thanks! Though this goes back to the comments of the anser of my other question that involves IdentityInfo and IdGenerators.. I then will have the issue that one of the objects in the list will be embedded and the rest will just be ids https://stackoverflow.com/a/46610026/986160