# Problem with saving/loading/parsing JSON using Jackson.databind ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

**Summary/Question:**
How do you save and load complex data structures to/from JSON using jackson-databind ObjectMapper? In my case jackson fails to re-establish objects referenced by id in the JSON string.

**Details:**
I am saving data with the following structure via Jackson.databind to a JSON-formatted file:

```
class Container {

     private HeaderClass header;
     private List<Class1> class1Data;
     private List<Class2> class2Data;

     public String generateJsonString() {
         List<Object> outputWrapper = new ArrayList<>();
         outputWrapper.add(header);
         outputWrapper.add(class1Data);
         outputWrapper.add(class2Data);

         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
         SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("Serializer/Deserializer module for DeviceAutomator configuration data") 
            .registerSubtypes(
                    HeaderClass.class,
                    Class1.class,
                    Class2.class);
         mapper.registerModule(module);
         mapper.writeValueAsString(outputWrapper);    

     }

     ... public field accessors, other methods ...    

}
```

the classes Class1 and Class2 are children of an abstract class ParentClass looking like this:

```
abstract class ParentClass {
     private String name;
     List<SomeEnum> enumItemList;

     ... getters and setters ...
}
```

Besides this List, Class1 and Class2 do have a number of simple fields.

Now, if I create a JSON String with `generateJsonString()`, in principle everything works fine. However, the items in `enumItemList` are resolved into some more complicated structures. The output look like this:

```
[ {
    "headerField1" : false,
    "headerField2" : 1000.0,
    ... some more header fields ...
}, [ { // List<Class1>.item1:
    "class1Field1" : 2.2523,
    ... more simple fields ...
    "enumItemList" : [ {
        "@type" : "SomeEnum",
        "@id" : "5cfd18f7-5f12-4434-8a5f-c9e0e6baaf5b",
        "name" : "name1"
    }, {
        "@type" : "SomeEnum",
        "@id" : "8101bc72-2bbc-4ddd-b8b0-c70f26a84fd9",
        "name" : "name2"
   }, 
   ... more list items ...
]}, { // List<Class1>.item2:
    "class1Field1" : 2.2523,
    ... more simple fields ...
    "enumItemList" : [ "5cfd18f7-5f12-4434-8a5f-c9e0e6baaf5b", "8101bc72-2bbc-4ddd-b8b0-c70f26a84fd9", ... more ids from above ... ],
} ], [ { // List<Class2>.item1:
    "class2Field1" : field1Value,
    "class2Field2" : field2Value,
    ... more fields ...,
    "enumItemList" : [ "5cfd18f7-5f12-4434-8a5f-c9e0e6baaf5b", ... more ids ... ]
} ] ]
```

If I read this string back from file to reconstruct my data objects, the code fails to resolve the references `"enumItemList": [ id1, id2, ...]` back to fully expanded objects but it works fine for the fully specified SomeEnum items.

This is how I process the Json String from file:

```
ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
jsonMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
jsonMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_INVALID_SUBTYPE);
jsonMapper.registerModule(module); // module from above
```

Comment: You did not provide the mapping configuration of your classes like `SomeEnum` this makes it hard to know what is going on.But have you looked at the Annotations `@JsonIdentityReference` also mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38445604/405793