# Parse Json with Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin

I have the following json to parse:

```json
{
"id":"123",
"nbElements":15,
"containers":[
  {
    "id":"cont1",
    "capacity":3
  }
],
"operations":[
  {
    "id":"cont1_01",
    "weight":3,
    "containerId":"cont1"
  },
  {
    "id":"cont1_02",
    "weight": 4, 
    "containerId":"cont1"
  }
]
}
```

Using quicktype, it suggests the following code:

```kotlin
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.*
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.*
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.*

val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper().apply {
    propertyNamingStrategy = PropertyNamingStrategy.LOWER_CAMEL_CASE
    setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
}

data class Welcome (
    @get:JsonProperty(required=true)@field:JsonProperty(required=true)
    val id: String,

    @get:JsonProperty(required=true)@field:JsonProperty(required=true)
    val nbElements: Long,

    @get:JsonProperty(required=true)@field:JsonProperty(required=true)
    val containers: List<Container>,

    @get:JsonProperty(required=true)@field:JsonProperty(required=true)
    val items: List<Item>
) {
    fun toJson() = mapper.writeValueAsString(this)

    companion object {
        fun fromJson(json: String) = mapper.readValue<Welcome>(json)
    }
}

data class Container (
    @get:JsonProperty(required=true)@field:JsonProperty(required=true)
    val id: String,

    @get:JsonProperty(required=true)@field:JsonProperty(required=true)
    val capacity: Long
)

data class Item (
    @get:JsonProperty(required=true)@field:JsonProperty(required=true)
    val id: String,

    @get:JsonProperty(required=true)@field:JsonProperty(required=true)
    val weight: Long,

    @get:JsonProperty("containerId", required=true)@field:JsonProperty("containerId", required=true)
    val containerID: String
)
```

I want to store the whole container object in each item instead of the `containerId` but I don't want to change the json, it must be done in the code.

More generally, is there  way to make the code  more concise? Is there  more suitable tool than jackson for example.

Comment: How about: [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization)

Comment: check this for jackson https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306040/jackson-deserialize-jsonidentityreference-alwaysasid-true